# How to change div style width for dynamically div tag in html in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, webix

I have `<span>title</span>` inside of `<div>... </div>`.

**title** is binding dynamically. My problem is Title text is ***not showing full text*** because some `<div>` tags are created dynamically with `Style="Width:150"`.

If change div tag property `width: auto`, my Title text was displaying properly after editing div with property in developer tool.

How to change to as below to `<div style=width:auto"..>`?

```
template: function (o) {
     return "<div> <span>" + o.Title + "</span> </div>"
}
```

[image: html tag]

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: Hey @ssyed! Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you add the AngularJS used to generate the code? Thanks!

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: @null version 1.6

Comment: @chris Happy, Code updated

Comment: @veg, updated code with style='position:absolute'. now its showing full text but its overwriting to next cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it appears that you are using WebIX, I suggest changing width when it is generated.

According to the documentation for a data view, the code would be something like this:

```
webix.ui({
    view:"dataview",
    container:"dataA",
    template: "<div class='webix_strong'>#title#</div> Year: #year#, rank: #rank#",
    data:...,
    datatype:"...",
    xCount:3, //the number of items in a row
    yCount:4, //the number of items in a column
    type:{
        width: 261,
        height: 90
    }   
});
```

If you have a static width, try setting the `width` to `auto` so it looks something like this:

```
webix.ui({
    view:"dataview",
    container:"dataA",
    template: function (o) {
        return "<div> <span>" + o.Title + "</span> </div>"
    },
    data:...,
    datatype:"...",
    xCount:3, //the number of items in a row
    yCount:4, //the number of items in a column
    type:{
        width: 'auto',
        height: 90
    }   
});
```

If it doesn't work, could you post your entire code between `webix.ui({` and `})`?

Comment: Thanks, @Vega! God bless :)